# Get coordinates of all pixels in a raster with rasterio

Tags: raster, rasterio

I have a n by m raster image in [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I would like to get the ground coordinates of all the pixels in this raster (ideally in an array of tuples). What would be an efficient way to do this?

This is what I have so far which is not efficient at all

```
file_name = 'sample.tif'
image = rasterio.open(file_name)
height, width = image.height, image.width
X_coord = np.zeros((image.height, image.width))
Y_coord = np.zeros((image.height, image.width))
for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        X_coord[row,col] = image.xy(row, col)[0]
        Y_coord[row,col] = image.xy(row, col)[1]
```

This piece of code loop through rows and columns in the image and uses the `.xy(row, col)` method to store `x` and `y` coordinates separately in two arrays. obviously, time-consuming and inefficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `rasterio.transform.xy` also accepts a sequence of rows and columns. So to avoid loops, create a meshgrid of every row and column.

```py
       file_name = 'sample.tif'
       with rasterio.open(file_name) as src:
            band1 = src.read(1)
            print('Band1 has shape', band1.shape)
            height = band1.shape[0]
            width = band1.shape[1]
            cols, rows = np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height))
            xs, ys = rasterio.transform.xy(src.transform, rows, cols)
            lons= np.array(xs)
            lats = np.array(ys)
            print('lons shape', lons.shape)
```

lats and lons should each have the same shape as band1.

Thanks to [MikeT's post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129857/51905) for showing how to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the nice answer from @intotecho. Lets say I want to find the indexes and center coordinates of all raster cells with a certain value.

I have a raster with 0 and 1 values. I want to find the ones:
[image]

```py
import rasterio
import numpy as np

rasterfile = r"C:/folder/5pixels_with_value_1.tif"
ds = rasterio.open(rasterfile, "r") #Read the raster
a = ds.read(1) #Read as a numpy array

height, width = a.shape #Find the height and width of the array

#Two arrays with the same shape as the input array/raster, where each value is the x or y index of that cell
cols, rows = np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height)) 

#Two arrays with the same shape as the input array/raster, where each value is the x or y coordinate of that cell 
xs, ys = rasterio.transform.xy(ds.transform, rows, cols) 

#They are actually lists, convert them to arrays
xcoords = np.array(xs)
ycoords = np.array(ys)

#Find all unique values in the array, with their counts
unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
counts = dict(zip(unique, counts))
#{0: 71805, 1: 5}

#I want to find the location of five the cells with the value of 1
xindex, yindex = np.where(a==1)
for x, y in zip(xindex, yindex):
    print(f"Index X: {x}, Y: {y}")
    # Index X: 29, Y: 167
    # Index X: 57, Y: 157
    # Index X: 61, Y: 135
    # Index X: 70, Y: 118
    # Index X: 109, Y: 166    
    
#What are their coordinates?
for x, y in zip(xindex, yindex):
    print(f"{xcoords[x,y]}, {ycoords[x,y]}")
    # 542059.3998, 6525045.1822
    # 542009.3998, 6524905.1822
    # 541899.3998, 6524885.1822
    # 541814.3998, 6524840.1822
    # 542054.3998, 6524645.1822
```