# Getting latitude and lontitude from TIF file using rasterio

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, latitude-longitude, rasterio

I refer to [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388047/get-coordinates-of-all-pixels-in-a-raster-with-rasterio) and want to get latitude and longitude from *.tif* file using rasterio.

My code is the same as the answer:

```py
with rasterio.open(path) as src:
        band1 = src.read(1)
        print('Band1 has shape', band1.shape)
        height = band1.shape[0]
        width = band1.shape[1]
        cols, rows = np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height))
        xs, ys = rasterio.transform.xy(src.transform, rows, cols)
        lons= np.array(xs)
        lats = np.array(ys)
        print('lons', lons)
        print('lats', lats)
```

And my tiff file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nNRlbjCiyjJgRyJXYOJS5l2ldqp_shcO/view?usp=sharing)

But the output of lats and lons are like this:
[image]

I think it must be wrong, the scale is obviously not latitude and lontitude. Could you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Your data is in a projected coordinate system that uses meters or feet as the X, Y units. You need to reproject it to a geographic coordinate system that uses degrees as the X, Y units.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your data seems to be in `EPSG:6933`, so rasterio is giving you the relevant coordinates for that projection.

If you want lat/lon you can use gdalwarp to reproject your raster in EPSG:4326 as:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326  input.tif output_4326.tif
```

and then use the code you provided.

You can also reproject using rasterio (see documentation [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/reproject.html)).

Comment: Thanks, I know what's the problem