# Acquiring data point coordinates from Geotiff and converting to numpy array

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, numpy, array

I would like to use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to interpolate my Sentinel-1 products (see two sample images below) taken from different orbits resulting in having the uniform datapoint coordinates.

I would like to use a similar approach as describe in [Smoothing/interpolating raster in Python using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/smoothing-interpolating-raster-in-python-using-gdal)

However, I am not able to figure it how to get points at which to interpolate data from a `geotiff`. So far, I have this for values and for basic geographic description:

```
from osgeo import gdal
# Loading terrain corrected image
master = gdal.Open("S1A_TC.tif")
# Data values of master image
master_array = master.ReadAsArray()
# Getting geographic data (e.g. pixelSizeX)    
gt = master.GetGeoTransform()
```

For getting array of data point coordinates or points at which to interpolate data, I found this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370069/converting-xy-co-ords-of-geotiff-to-numpy-array-positions-in-python

The GDAL link is dead and I am not able to found something useful.

How can I read the data point coordinates as `np.array`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: broken link is now https://gdal.org/user/raster_data_model.html

Comment: @nmtoken I am still confused. I am not sure if it will solve my issue... What are `Xpixel` and `Yline`? Thx

Comment: Xpixel and Yline are the column and row positions, respectively, of a pixel in the grid. Notice the paragraph a bit further down about corners vs. pixel centers.

Comment: @TurePålsson Okay... I will go through it more thoroughly and try to understand it. Of course, if you would like to a write an answer, you are welcome! :-)

Comment: Hmm I think that my question could be a duplication of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129847/obtain-coordinates-and-corresponding-pixel-values-from-geotiff-using-python-gdal?rq=1

But not quite certain about it (Since I am working with Sentinel-1 satellite imagery). Strange that I didn't find it during the writing of the topic...